# Paypal recurring payments or one off payment

Tags: html, paypal

Im building a form that has the option of a one off payment or recurring payments.
and I have a tick box to state the amount should be recurring or not.

But Paypal is not picking it up and I can't find the correct name to give the box at the moment it looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Recurring" value="Yes" />
```

is there away of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check the documentation of PayPal html variables on recurring following this link:

https://www.paypalobjects.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_std-variable-ref-subscribe.html